# sharepoint 2013 workflow send e-mail when new task is created

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I'm creating a workflow in Sharepoint Designer 2013 and I want to send an e-mail when a new task is created in a task list. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a workflow for that task list and check the "Creating a new item will start this workflow" checkbox.